# Get last record in GroupBy() Grouping

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core

I'm writing a group of records to a CSV file grouped by car number and lap number:

```
foreach (var group in telemetryRecords.GroupBy(x => (x.Car, x.Lap)))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(@$"{outputPath}\Car{group.Key.Car}");
    using TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(@$"{outputPath}\Car{group.Key.Car}\Car{group.Key.Car} Lap{group.Key.Lap:D3}.csv");
    WriteCsvHeader(tw);
    WriteDoubleGroupedCsvLine(tw, group);
}
```

This code writes the appropriate files, but I want to append the total lap time to each filename.

Each TelemetryRecord contains elapsed lap times, and so the final record of each lap group is the total lap time:

```
Car #, Lap #, elapsed time
22,7,00:00:33.189
22,7,00:01:03.152 <-- This is the total lap time for lap 7
22,8,00:00:00.089
22,8,00:00:00.182
22,8,00:01:20.344 <-- This is the total lap time for lap 8
22,9,00:00:00.442
```

How can I get the final elapsed time for each lap and then append it to the filename?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I just needed to add the following after the opening line of my foreach statement:

```
var lapTime = group.Last();
```

I was then able to get the last item from each ElapsedLapTime record from the lapTime var:

```
foreach (var group in telemetryRecords.GroupBy(x => (x.Car, x.Lap)))
{
    var lapTime = group.Last();
    Directory.CreateDirectory(@$"{outputPath}\Car{group.Key.Car}");
    using TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(@$"{outputPath}\Car{group.Key.Car}\Car{group.Key.Car} Lap{group.Key.Lap:D3} {lapTime.ElapsedLapTime.ToString().Replace(":", "-").Replace(".", "-")}.csv");
    WriteCsvHeader(tw);
    WriteDoubleGroupedCsvLine(tw, group);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what "append it to the filename" means, but the last record could be obtained with `.Last()`. In your case `.Max()` may be more appropriate.

Here a snippet of how this could look like.

*`lines` are the lines from your example*

```
// no error handling for brevity
var data = lines
    .Select( l => l.Split(','))
    .Select(a => (Car: a[0], Lap: a[1], LapTime: TimeSpan.Parse(a[2])));

var maxes = data.GroupBy(
    x => (x.Car, x.Lap),
    x => x.LapTime,
    (key, values) => (key.Car, key.Lap, values.Max()));
```

If the input is always sorted, `Last` will work as well.

```
    (key, values) => (key.Car, key.Lap, values.Last()));
```

---

EDIT

The file name would be something like:

```
var fileName = @$"{outputPath}\Car{group.Key.Car}\Car{group.Key.Car} Lap{group.Key.Lap:D3} {group.Last().LapTime}.csv"
    .Replace(":", "");
```

but please be careful with

Comment: This line:

using TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(@$"{outputPath}\Car{group.Key.Car}\Car{group.Key.Car} Lap{group.Key.Lap:D3}.csv");
    WriteCsvHeader(tw);

Results in a filename of: Car8 Lap013.csv and so forth. I want them to read:

Car8 Lap013 00:00:123.453 <-- this number being the last elapsed time of lap 13.

Comment: Ok, updated the answer. You are looking for something like `group.Last().LapTime`.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm a bit confused as to where the code goes. In my foreach statement above, would I switch the telemetryRecords.GroupBy(x => (x.Car, x.Lap)) with the GroupBy shown in the Maxes variable? I tried doing that (except with values.Max() swapped with values.Last()), but in doing so  {group.Key.Car} and the other variables in the filenames are throwing a CS1061 error.

Comment: In your code `Lap{group.Key.Lap:D3}.csv"` -> `Lap{group.Key.Lap:D3} {group.Last().LapTime}.csv"`. Because Laptime has ":" in it, and file names in Windows cannot contain ":" you need to get rid of ":"s (that's why my example has `.Replace`)

Comment: I tried using .Replace, but the compiler is producing a  a CS1061 error on the .Key values group.Key.Lap, group.Key.Car, etc. in the file export line.